# How to Print Bind Variables in Java Prepared Statements.

Tags: java, database

Suppose My query is like this, Here conn is connection Object :

```
String countrycode=91;//it is dynamic in my case
String query = "update tblemployeedata set countrycode='?';
PreparedStatement pstmtUpdate = conn.prepareStatement(query);
pstmtUpdate.setString(1,countrycode);
```

Now after setting above country code, I want to see my actual query formed like

```
update tblemployeedata set countrycode='91';

pstmtUpdate.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pstmtUpdate.toString()` method to see the actual query that is made after setting the parameters in the prepared statement.

Comment: This query will not print the parameters received, it will print ? instead of params.

Comment: @BhavikAmbani No it will print the parameter values if they were already set before `toString` method is called.

Comment: @Abu. It will not print at least not in my case.In my case it is printing ::org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement@1479ef9

Comment: In my case its printing `com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement[1] - select name from abu.employee where salary=1000`

Comment: @Abu Thats what I am saying that this will not print the parameterized query.

Comment: @BhavikAmbani that is what OP wants "I want to see my actual query" that is ? replaced with actual values.

Comment: @Abu Please refer by answer for the prepared statement query printing.

Answer (score -2):

You can get the value of the query by the following way.

```
Class stmt1 = pstmtUpdate.getClass();
java.lang.reflect.Field mem = stmt1.getField("sql");
String value= (String)mem.get(pstmt);
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: OP want to see `update tblemployeedata set countrycode='91';` (entire query) and not `91` (value that is set)

Comment: My answer will print the complete query with set value of the query

Comment: it is giving me no such field Exception. can u elaborate this example more

Comment: @Prateek Yes, you can elaborate

Comment: @Bhavik: your answer does not work (or maybe with some specific driver only). Prateek asked for some details and you wrote a strange comment to him ?

Comment: The problem is that this solution will only work with implementations of PreparedStatement with a field named "sql" that contains the query. I don't know such an implementation, though it's quite possible that it exists. But regardless, the question was how to get the set values for bind variables, not  how to get the query. Just FYI, the latter is a known problem of PreparedStatement as the interface doesn't define a way to get the query. There are some implementations that use .toString() to reveal it, but others don't.